# Calculated fields in HTML form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with DreamWeaver, PHP, MySQL, JQuery Mobile and JavaScript. I am showing MySQL records on a table and each row has an edit link to open an update record file. Using JavaScript in an insert record file, I am able to calculate fields values using a JavaScript function, but now, I am trying to do the same in an update record file.

The problem I have now, is that on the second file the JavaScript function is called, but any calculation is made.

The only difference I see there is that on the second file (update record) the fields already have a value, but I am not sure if that is the source of the problem, but I guess not, then the user can manually change the values.

This is the JavaScript code for both files:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calculatetotal(){
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    var mat = 0;
    mat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mat').value);
    var mo = 0;
    mo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mo').value);
    var uti = 0;
    uti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('uti').value);
    var ind = 0;
    ind = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ind').value);
    var poriva = 0;
    poriva = parseFloat(document.getElementById('poriva').value);
    var  totaliva =0;
    var totcliente =0;
    totcliente = (mat+mo+uti+ind).toFixed(2);;
    var totaliva = ((poriva)/100)*totcliente;
    document.getElementById('totCliente').value = (mat+mo+uti+ind).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('totaliva').value = totaliva; 
    document.getElementById('totalpre').value= parseFloat(totaliva)+parseFloat(totcliente);
}
</script>
```

I need your help to understand why is it working on the insert record file and not on the update record file.

This is the code for the form part in HTML from the update record part:

```
  <form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" data-ajax="false" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
            <table align="center">
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Obra:</td>
                <td><select name="int_obra">
                  <?php 
do {  
?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['idObra']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset2['idObra'], htmlentities($row_Recordset1['int_obra'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_Recordset2['nombreObra']?></option>
                  <?php
} while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2));
?>
                </select></td>
              <tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Materiales:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dbl_materiales" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_materiales'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32"   id="mat"  onChange="calculatetotal()"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Mano de Obra:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dbl_mano_de_obra" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_mano_de_obra'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" id="mo" onChange="calculatetotal()"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Utilidad:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dbl_utilidad" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_utilidad'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" id="uti" onChange="calculatetotal()"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Indirectos:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dbl_indirectos" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_indirectos'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="ind" onChange="calculatetotal()"size="32"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Pre. aprobado por cliente:</td>
                <td><input name="dbl_total" type="text" id="totcliente"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_total'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" readonly></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">% IVA:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="dbl_porcentaje_iva" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_porcentaje_iva'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" id="poriva" onChange="calculatetotal()"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">Total IVA:</td>
                <td><input name="dbl_total_iva" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_total_iva'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" id="totaliva" readonly></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">TOTAL DEL PRESUPUESTO:</td>
                <td><strong>
                <input name="dbl_total_presupuesto" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_Recordset1['dbl_total_presupuesto'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" id="totalpre" readonly>
                </strong></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">MONEDA:</td>
                <td><select name="int_moneda">
                  <option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, htmlentities($row_Recordset1['int_moneda'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>PESO MXN</option>
                  <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, htmlentities($row_Recordset1['int_moneda'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>USD</option>
                </select></td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="baseline">
                <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Actualizar Presupuesto"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
            <input type="hidden" name="idPresupuesto" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['idPresupuesto']; ?>">
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the JavaScript code, and now it works as expected. Thank you for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calculatetotal(){

    var mat = 0;
    mat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mat').value);
    var mo = 0;
    mo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mo').value);
    var uti = 0;
    uti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('uti').value);
    var ind = 0;
    ind = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ind').value);
    var poriva = 0;
    poriva = parseFloat(document.getElementById('poriva').value);

    totcliente = (mat+mo+uti+ind).toFixed(2);
    var totaliva = parseFloat(((poriva)/100)*totcliente);
    document.getElementById('totcliente').value = totcliente;
    document.getElementById('totaliva').value = totaliva.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('totalpre').value = (parseFloat(totcliente)+parseFloat(totaliva)).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

add your script a the end of the page juste before `</body>` and call the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function calculatetotal(){
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    var mat = 0;
    mat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mat').value);
    var mo = 0;
    mo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('mo').value);
    var uti = 0;
    uti = parseFloat(document.getElementById('uti').value);
    var ind = 0;
    ind = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ind').value);
    var poriva = 0;
    poriva = parseFloat(document.getElementById('poriva').value);
    var  totaliva =0;
    var totcliente =0;
    totcliente = (mat+mo+uti+ind).toFixed(2);;
    var totaliva = ((poriva)/100)*totcliente;
    document.getElementById('totCliente').value = (mat+mo+uti+ind).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('totaliva').value = totaliva; 
    document.getElementById('totalpre').value= parseFloat(totaliva)+parseFloat(totcliente);
}

calculatetotal();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean, I need to call the JavaScript every time  a field value changes..thank you for your answer

Comment: I mean your javascript tag should be after your HTML tag. And you have to calculatetotal() if you want to init it. I mean the onchange works if the user change the value. so add `<script>calculatetotal();</script>` after your script injection

Comment: In the current code, every time a field value changes, the alert message included in the javascript function is launched, I guess than means the javascript is being called as needed. I don't understand what you mean when you say 'add <script>calculate total()... after your script injection. Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: add before the tag </body> the code `<script> function calculatetotal(){ //your js code } calculatetotal();</script>`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working. I am using the same js code in the insert record file, and there is it working, no need to insert calculate(); at the end of it.

Comment: Can you add all details about your updating process. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have answered my own question with the updated JavaScript code. Finally I have changed it a little to make it working.